# How to install Java Runtime Environment 7 update 5 for x64 arquitecture on Debian OS?

Tags: debian, software-installation, java

**The History:**
Hey guys I want to install JRE7u5 and not OpenJRE7u5 because, while doing a research on the web I discovery that Minecraft runs better on JRE, than with 
OpenJRE.

**The Failure:**
But the [here](http://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml) (instructions for Linux x64) and [here](http://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml) (instructions for Linux x64 RPM) are not helpful, I already tried to download both and I used `alien` and `rpm` to try install the RPM package, but everything goes wrong.

**The question:**
Knowing that I would like to request a tutorial teaching me how to install JRE7u5 (Java Runtime Environment 7 update 5) for x64 architecture, and just for inclusion, I'm using Debian 6.

Comment: First things first - have you tried the `openjdk` java?  It's the recommended distribution on Debian systems.  If not, then I'd try the [`java-package`](http://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) route first, before the wiki-how link.  With a packaging system as mature as Debian's, always treat generic instructions that involve manually copying and symlink-ing lots of files with a healthy dose of suspicion.  With Debian, there's usually a cleaner or, for lack of a better word, more "Debian-way" method.

Comment: @jw013 I already tried `openjdk`, "while doing a research on the web I discovery that Minecraft runs better on JRE, than with OpenJRE", and java-package is obsolete, as page on the link says.

Comment: what distribution are you using? you can get java7 for ubuntu here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

Comment: @ysangkok as the title says "How to install Java Runtime Environment 7 update 5 for x64 arquitecture on Debian OS?", I'm using Debian

Answer (score -1):

I found an article How to install Oracle Java JDK 7 from http://namhuy.net/1195/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-7.html

To intall Java Runtime Environment on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

> apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

To intall package to developing programs using Java on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.

> apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk